# Populate GridView using JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, gridview

I'm retrieving data from Server side using `AJAX` and then converting it into `JSON` Array, then I'm applying filters according to my need and finally, I want to use the filtered data to populate `GridView` in the client side.

Is there any way using which I can bind the data to the GridView in client side code? Also, if I need to send the `JSON` Array back to Server side then how it'll be done?

Comment: Why not retrieve the JSON server side and bind it to the gridview?

Comment: @VDWWD I also asked that in my question, can you suggest some article in which it's explained how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to retrieve the JSON string on server side using JSON.NET

then convert from json to dataset

```
public DataTable convertJSON()
{       
    string json = JSONSTRINGDATA;  
    var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
    return table;
}
```

and set datasource of the gridview

```
GridView1.DataSource = convertJSON();
GridView1.DataBind();
```